# Source map file generator

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/juhp/sourcemap) in my haskell program to generate a source map file, but getting some performance issue. The size of the mapping file generated was about 30M bytes, and it took almost 130 secs to get it. It's much more slower than I expected, though I can not figure out what's the problem causing it. Here's my code looks like:

```
generateSrcMap :: String -> [FilePath] -> SourceRange -> Value
generateSrcMap sFile srcs sourceRanges =
  generate $
    SourceMapping
      { smFile = sFile,
        smSources = srcs,
        smSourceRoot = Nothing,
        smMappings = mappings
      }
  where
    mappings = mapMaybe getMapping $ zip sourceRanges [0 ..]

    getMapping :: (SourceRange, Int) -> Maybe Mapping
    getMapping (SourceRange start _ _, idx) =
      if srcFile == "std"
        then Nothing -- skip mapping stdlib code
        else
          Just $
            Mapping
              { mapGenerated = Pos 1 $ fromInteger $ toInteger idx, -- business logic, use index as column
                mapOriginal = Just (Pos line column),
                mapSourceFile = Just srcFile,
                mapName = Nothing
              }
      where
        !srcFile = sourceName start
        !line = fromInteger $ toInteger (1 + unPos (sourceLine start))
        !column = fromInteger $ toInteger $ unPos $ sourceColumn start
```

Also I tried using [this rust library](https://github.com/getsentry/rust-sourcemap) to run decode/encode the same source map json file. It turns out to be much faster than the Haskell code I wrote. It took ~14 secs for decoding and ~3 secs for encoding. So any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/278277/revisions#rev-body-b2a43755-d191-45d5-b500-b1be938ff7de) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Could you post the definition of the `SourceRange` type or where it can be found?